# Using SQL Minus Operator in python

Tags: python, sql, oracle

I want to perform a minus operation like the code below on two tables.

```
SELECT
    column_list_1
FROM
    T1
MINUS 
SELECT
    column_list_2
FROM
    T2;
```

This is after a migration has happened. I have these two databases that I have connected like this:

```
import cx_Oracle
import pandas as pd
import pypyodbc
source = cx_Oracle.connect(user, password, name)
df = pd.read_sql(""" SELECT * from some_table """, source)

target = pypyodbc.connect(blah, blah, db) 
df_2 = pd.read_sql(""" SELECT * from some_table """, target)
```

How can I run a minus operation on the source and target databases in python using a query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have a DB link then you can do a MINUS or you can use merge from Pandas.

```
df = pd.read_sql(""" SELECT * from some_table """, source)
df_2 = pd.read_sql(""" SELECT * from some_table """, target) 


df_combine = df.merge(df2.drop_duplicates(),how='right', indicator=True)
print(df3)
```

There will be a new column _merge created in df_combine which will contain values both (row present in both the data frame) and right_only (row in data frame df).

In the same way you can join a left merge.

Answer (score 3):

Choose either one:

1. Use Python in order to perform a "manual" MINUS operation between the two result sets.
2. Use Oracle by means of a dblink. In this case, you won't need to open two connections from Python.